# Renaming duplicated list "L" to "R" in Maya python

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

What I want to do is duplicate a controller to other side and rename/replace `_L` to `_R`. So I just have to select controller and it will create a group and then another group to mirror it on right side and renaming that other group to `_R`. Then unparent first group to world. thats all I want to do. but I'm stuck on renaming. I know I have to sort list in reverse order to rename it but whenever I do it Maya says:

`More than one object matches name`

Duplicated object has different parent name and same children name. Please tell me how should I do it and what I'm missing.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

list = cmds.ls(sl=1)
grp = cmds.group(em=1, name=("grp" + list[0]))

# creating constraint to match transform and deleting it
pc = cmds.pointConstraint(list, grp, o=[0,0,0], w=1)
oc = cmds.orientConstraint(list, grp, o=[0,0,0], w=1)
cmds.delete(pc, oc)

# parenting it to controller
cmds.parent(list, grp)

# creating new group to reverse it to another side
Newgrp = cmds.group(em=1)
cmds.parent(grp, Newgrp)
Reversedgrp = cmds.duplicate(Newgrp)

cmds.setAttr(Reversedgrp[0] +'.sx', -1)

selection = cmds.ls(Reversedgrp, long=1)
selection.sort(key=len, reverse=1)
```

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldnt name a variable `list` in python.

Comment: @NickA is right, you shouldn't name your variables with Python reserved words. Make sure you rename `list` to `_list` or anything not reserved; it might be related, it might be not, your script's behaviour becomes quite unpredictable.
Also, you might want to use the `long` parameter when you call `cmds.ls()` in the first line too, as such: `_list = cmds.ls(sl=1, long=1)`

Comment: Where is the part of the code where you rename your objects?

Comment: yeah ill change it

Answer (score 2):

Renaming in Maya is very annoying, because the names are your only handle to the objects themselves.

The usually trick is basically:

1. Duplicate the items with the `rr` flag, so you only get the top nodes
2. Use `listRelatives`  with the `ad` and `full` flags to get all the children of the duplicated top node in long form like  `|Parent|Child|Grandchild`. In this form the where the entire hierarchy above the name is listed in order (you can get this form with `cmds.ls(l=True)` on objects as well)
3. Sort that list and then reverse it.  This will put the longest path names first, so you can start with the leaf nodes and work your way upwards
4. Now loop through the items and apply your renaming pattern

So something like this, though you probably want to replace the selection here with something you control:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
dupes = cmds.duplicate(cmds.ls(sl=True), rr=True)   # duplicate, return only roots
dupes += cmds.listRelatives(dupes, ad=True, f=True) # add children as long names
longnames = cmds.ls(dupes, l=True)                 # make sure we have long name for root
longnames.sort()     # usually these sort automatically, but's good to be safe
for item in longnames[::-1]:   # this is shorthand for 'walk through the list backwards'
    shortname = item.rpartition("|")[-1]  # get the last bit of the name
    cmds.rename(item, shortname.replace("r","l"))   # at last, rename the item
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks "theodox" it was very usefull. but still little bit confused in sorting, long names, short names and .rpartition... but anyway i have created this script finally.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
_list = cmds.ls(sl=1)
grp = cmds.group(em=1, name=("grp_"+ _list[0]))

#creating constraint to match transfor and deleting it.
pc=cmds.pointConstraint( _list, grp, o=[0,0,0],w=1 )
oc=cmds.orientConstraint( _list, grp, o=[0,0,0],w=1 )
cmds.delete(pc,oc)


cmds.parent( _list, grp )
Newgrp=cmds.group(em=1)
cmds.parent(grp,Newgrp)

#duplicating new group and reversing it to negative side
dupes = cmds.duplicate(cmds.ls(Newgrp,s=0), rr=True)   # duplicate,     return only roots

cmds.setAttr( dupes[0] +'.sx', -1 )

#renaming
dupes += cmds.listRelatives(dupes, ad=True, f=True) # add children as long names
longnames = cmds.ls(dupes, l=True,s=0)                 # make sure we have long name for root
longnames.sort()     # usually these sort automatically, but's good to be safe
print longnames
for item in longnames[::-1]:   # this is shorthand for 'walk through the list backwards'
    shortname = item.rpartition("|")[-1]  # get the last bit of the name
    cmds.rename(item, shortname.replace("_L","_R"))   # at last, rename the item

#ungrouping back to world and delting unused nodes
cmds.parent( grp, world=True )
duplicatedGrp=cmds.listRelatives(dupes[0], c=True)
cmds.parent( duplicatedGrp, world=True )

cmds.delete(dupes[0],Newgrp)
```

anyone can use this code for mirroring controllers just change "l","r" in rename command.

thank you.